# unable to click on Webelement on web Page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on web element and enter text inside it.

Steps:

1. Launch "https://www.phptravels.net/"
2. Click on tours tab.
3. Perform send keys operation on search field.

1.I tried using click on search box and entering text via send keys but unable to do so, After that I performed click action and send keys using javaScript but this is also not working.

2. I have written different xpath for the same but no positive results.

//code is as below

```
public class HandlingDropDown2 {

    static WebElement element;
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Driver/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();        
        driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/");

        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Tours     ')]"));
        element.click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Got it!')]"));

        element.click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='s2id_autogen5']"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

        System.out.println("clicked on autogen box");

        //element.click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active']"));

        JavascriptExecutor executor2 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor2.executeScript("arguments[0].'value='Test';",element);
        //element.sendKeys("test"); 
    }
}
```

Expected Result: User must be able to enter some text via automation.

Actual Result: Unable to perform click and sendkeys using JavaScript and simple selenium methods.

Comment: What error do you get? Is the page populated by ajax? You should not use Thread.sleep but WebDriverWait instead. If you are unsure about your xPath, google chrome developer tools allow you to copy the correct xpath expressions for nodes easily.

Comment: @kilian - I'm getting below error
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active']"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088

Comment: I have also used webdriver element locator addon for firefox also using chrome path addon for chrome browser. xpath is valid but script fails by giving error as "unable to locate element"

Comment: During investigation I found that the class name of that element was dynamically changing whenever we perform click on that element so I preferred using xpath like  "//div[@id='select2-drop']//input[starts-with(@class,'select2-input')]" which resolved my issue. 
Thanks @kilin.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the functionality of sendKeys

Fir of all, your `xPath` is div element and you are trying to do `sendKeys` in div element which is wrong. If you observed there is span element named 'Search by Listing or City Name'. If you click there then your input element gets visible where you can `click()` and `sendKeys("")`

Try,

```
// click on below span element to get input visibled,
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Search by Listing or City Name']"));
element.click();
```

Then your input element is now available where you can click and sendkeys

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='select2-drop']//input[@class='select2-input'][last()]"));
element.click();
element.sendKeys("test");
```